# juego de loteria en java

Tags: java

Hola soy nueva programando y he estado intentando hacer un juego de loteria, tal vez sea algo simple para alquien con experiencia, pero a mi se me ha estado complicando bastante, el juego va asi :
se pueden vender 5 numeros por persona el cual se debe validar que no se repita ni uno. El usuario ingresara el nombre y los numeros.

El juego generara 5 numeros al azar entre 0 y 100 y buscaran los 5 numeros en las 5 columnas por cada fila, si encuentra al menos 3 numeros iguales gana $5000, si encuentra 4 gana $10,000, si encuentra los 5 ganara 100,000 y mostrara los nombres de los ganadores
este es mi avance
si alguien puede ayudarme, gracias de antemano ;)

```
 Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
        int opcion, contadorNombres=0, contadorNumeros=0,diario;
        String respuesta;
        try{
           //BIENVENIDA AL USUARIO
            System.out.println("Bienvenido al juego de la loteria");

                do {
                        //MENU DE OPCIONES DE JUEGO
                        System.out.println("Menu de opciones de juego");
                        System.out.println("1. Juego Diario");
                        System.out.println("2. Juego Semanal");
                        System.out.println("3. Juego Mensual");
                        System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion");
                        opcion = teclado.nextInt();

                        switch (opcion)
                        {
                            case 1: // solo se pueden vender 5 numeros por persona
                                System.out.println("Juego Diario");

                                //ARREGLO NOMBRES DE CLIENTES

                                String [] clientes =  new String [5];
                                int [] numeros = new int [5];
                                 for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                                 {     System.out.println(" ingrese su nombre");
                                     clientes[i] = teclado.next();
                                     contadorNombres++;
                                     for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
                                     {
                                         System.out.println(" [" + j + "] Ingrese un numero : " );
                                         numeros[j] = teclado.nextInt();
                                         contadorNumeros++;
                                         if (j > 0) {
                                             while (validar(numeros, j, numeros[j])) {
                                                 System.out.println(" ERROR! " + numeros[j] + " esta repetido, ingrese otro numero");
                                                 numeros[j] = teclado.nextInt();
                                             }
                                         }

                                     }

                                 }

                                //NUMEROS AL AZAR
                                int [] azar = new int [5];
                                //s=fila , g=columna
                                for (int s = 0; s<5; s++ )
                                {
                                        azar[s] = obtenerNumeroAzar();

                                }
                                  //LECTURA DE NUMEROS AL AZAR
                                for (int s = 0; s<5; s++ )
                                {
                                    System.out.println(azar[s]);

                                }

                                System.out.println("\n");

                              break
}
```

Comment: Las preguntas que solo exponen enunciados de tareas sin mayor avance de parte de quien expone la duda no son bien vistas y terminan cerradas, lee [ask]

Comment: Algo así? https://github.com/SebastianEPH/Python_JuegoApuestas_Consola

Comment: Disculpe pero creo que te falta completar el try/catch y el do/while.

Comment: Cuando se hacen preguntas buscando ayuda con la depuración del código es necesario incluir un [mre], además de especificar los errores que se tienen... si el código que nos pasas no *compila* porque falta código, cómo vamos a poder ayudarte??

Comment: Entonces se ingresan 5 personas que pueden comprar hasta 5 números cada una?? Y necesitas un método que compare los números de los jugadores con los del sorteo. Tiene que ser un array o puede ser otra estructura de datos?

Comment: @SebastiánEPH si algo asi es

Comment: @LucasRox es con arraylist

Comment: @Benito-B la pagina no me permite poner mucho codigo :/